# implementing or defining class or function declared inside an unnamed/anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, implementation

Is it legal to define the implementation of a function or class members outside the unnamed (anonymous) namespace they've been defined inside.
My compiler accepts it but I want to be sure it's legal
e.g.

```
////////////////
// foo.cpp 

namespace {
 struct X
 {
 void foo(int x);
 };
}

// Is this legal?
void X::foo(int x)
{
}
```

The reason is I would like to avoid the unnecessary indentation imposed by our uncrustify formatting

Comment: I think (but I'm not 100%) the anonymous isn't a namespace per se (so you're fine for declarations), it just means that instances declared in it (variables and functions) have static linkage, i.e. they are local to the translation unit.

Comment: @Kerrek: To my understanding they are in fact namespaces, which have a different name for each translation unit. And act like: `namespace <anonymous-namespace> { /*...*/ } using namespace <anonymous-namespace>;` So rules like Koenig lookup should apply to them aswell.

Comment: @smerlin:  Right, except that for obscure name lookup reasons, it's actually equivalent to `namespace unique_name { } using namespace unique_name; namespace unique_name { /* contents go here */ }`

Comment: @smerlin: I see - so it does affect declarations? What's the fully qualified name of `X` then?

Comment: @Kerrek:  Names declared in an unnamed namespace may in fact have external linkage.  It just doesn't matter because there is no way to refer to them from another translation unit (the unique name is not available).

Answer (score 4):

It is really no different than the following, which is totally legit:

```
namespace ns {
    struct s {
        void f();
    };
}

using namespace ns;

void s::f() { }
```

The names from the named namespace are brought into the global namespace and thus definitions can be provided for them there.  The only difference with the unnamed namespace is that it has no name (really, it has some unique, unutterable name) and the `using namespace` is implicit.

Comment: This is not correct, both can be used for different purpose. You cannot define global variables in named `namespace`; however in unnamed `namespace` you can! When unnamed `namespace` is declared in a .h file, it creates unique copy for all definitions in the `.cpp` file it's included.

Comment: unnamed `namespace` generates a unique copy of all variables defined in it for every translation unit; named `namespace` cannot do that. I have edited my answer for more detail.

Comment: @iammilind:  Yes, that follows directly from the fact that the unnamed namespace has a different name in each translation unit, which means that every entity declared in an unnamed namespace has a different fully qualified name in each translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace
{
  struct X
  {
     X(int);
     int x_;
  };
}

X::X(int x) : x_(x) {}

int main()
{
   X x(5);

   cout << x.x_ << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Compiles (and runs) under gcc 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's perfectly legal. The difference an *unnamed namespace* makes is that, the content of the namespace is available only within the file it's declared. If it's in `.h` file then, it will be added to all the subsequent `.cpp` file and every `.cpp` file will have a unique copy of the contents of the `namespace`.

In fact it's a better way to declare a global `static` variable. Now see, what kind of difference it will make:

```
namespace {
 struct X
 {
   void foo(int x);
 };
 int i;  // declare this global variable
}
```

If you put this code inside a header file then, wherever that header file is `#include`ed, all those `.cpp` file will have a different copy of `int i;` inside them. Changing the value of `i` in one `.cpp` file doesn't affect the other `.cpp` file.

Moreover, it will not give linker error for multiple definitions, since it's in unnamed `namespace`.

**Edit**: To evaluate it more, define the namespace as following:

```
// x.h
namespace
{
  struct X
  {
    void foo(int x)
    {
      static int c;  // static inside the function
      cout<<"a = "<<(c++)<<endl;
    }
  };
}
```

Now `#include` this header file in 2 different `.cpp` files. In both of them try to call `foo()` with object of `X`. It will print:

```
a = 0
a = 0
```

Which means that `X::foo()` **in both the** `.cpp` **files are different**. If you give the `namespace` a name and repeat the same thing, it will output

```
a = 0
a = 1
```

**Thus unnamed `namespace` creates a different copy for each translation unit.**

Answer (score 0):

It's legal in your scenario, but in one scenario, it will cause compiler ambiguous error.

In case have another class in X.h:

```
// X.h
struct X
{
    void foo(int x) { }
};
```

And in foo.cpp, need to use the X defined in X.h

```
////////////////
// foo.cpp 
#include "X.h"

namespace {
    struct X
    {
        void foo(int x);
    };

    // use the X declared in anonymous namespace
    void test()
    {
        X x;
        x.foo(3);
    }
}

// reference to 'X' is ambiguous
void X::foo(int x)
{
}

void otherFunction()
{
    // Use struct X in X.h
    ::X x;
    x.foo(3);
}
```

if leave the implementation code out of the anonymous namespace, compiler complains ambiguous. If move the implementation code inside anonymous namespace, it works fine.